# Synaptics forgets Min/MaxSpeed on startup

Tags: touchpad, startup, synaptics

I am using a 2013 11' MacBookAir running Ubuntu 16.04 and I am striving to get the Touchpad work as close as possible to MacOSX settings. I am using Synaptics which does a pretty good job, I think. A very bizarre phenomenon, though, is that when I save my settings in the /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf file and reboot, they are all applied but the three (MinSpeed, MaxSpeed, AccelFactor) affecting cursor speed.

I have modified other parameters (e.g. FingerHigh/FingerLow, MaxTapMove, etc) and they work as they should, namely on startup they coincide with those in my 50-synaptics.conf file *although they are not the default values*. On the other hand, the three speed parameters keep on remaining the same.

I attach a screenshot of my 50-synaptics.conf file and of a terminal window where I run synclient -l.

[image: terminal window]

[image: 50-synaptics.conf]

Comment: Dont use images when posting text but do copy/paste the text and format it. Makes it a lot easier to find your topic when searching.

Comment: @Rinzwind: I see what you mean, and I apologise. I wanted to avoid people telling me that I have to do that-and-that on 50-synaptics.conf which I have already done...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to work out this issue, by creating a simple shell containing the required command and putting it into `/usr/local/bin` after having made it executable via `chmod`. Then I added the name of this shell to the Startup Applications, and everything was ok.