# Can't understand systemd in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, startup, systemd

I am trying to fight against some Synaptics commands which are not executed on startup by Ubuntu 16.04 (on my MacBookAir), as detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842314/synaptics-forgets-min-maxspeed-on-startup). After trying with rc.local I realised that I have to create a systemd service instead. So I

1) Created a file with two lines

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Hello, world.' > Desktop/foo.txt
```

and saved as `/usr/bin/touchpad`. Then I made it executable via `chmod`.

2) I created a file

```
[Unit]
Description=Touchpad

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/touchpad

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and saved it as `/etc/systemd/system/touchpad.service`. Made this executable, too.

3) Finally, I run

```
systemctl enable touchpad.service
```

I shut down and started up again hoping to see a file on the Desktop named `foo.txt` with the text `Hello, world` in it, but nothing happens. What is wrong?

Comment: `multi-user.target` is pure text mode where you have multiple TTYs to log in, but no graphical interface yet. In that environment, you can not launch GUI apps at all. Normally on a desktop installation, you boot to `graphical.target`. However, that only gets you to the login screen (i.e. lightdm by default) and you have no logged in user yet, so again you are not in an environment to launch GUI apps (at least in a way that you would see an open window later after logging in). So AFAIK you can not launch GUI user apps with systemd at all, that must be done after the login completed.

Comment: So do not launch any GUI (or even interactive command-line) application but only scripts that do not open any windows or depend on any desktop / X server / dbus stuff for any other reason or require user interaction (pressing a key, etc) using systemd. Instead launch scripts or applications that may run unattended and produce no or only command-line output.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thanks for your hint, that I did not know. Then I tried to change my scritp from gnome-terminal to synaptics MinSpeed=0.6 (see the modified question), which—as far as I understand—does not require neither interaction, nor depends upon any server: but still this does not work.

Comment: I don't know what Synaptics does or doesn't, but it might e.g. require dbus or some Xinput stuff. Try something else, like a simple Bash script that creates a file.

Comment: OK, then I have tried modifying the script to a more basic echo 'Hello, world.' > Desktop/foo.txt which does its job when called simply by bash touchpad but not at startup...

Comment: Indeed, if I try to run systemctl start touchpad.service (and nothing happens) followed by systemctl status touchpad.service, I get the following message

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/touchpad.service; enabled; vendor preset:
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fr 2016-10-28 15:06:28 BST; 2s ago
  Process: 2443 ExecStart=/usr/bin/touchpad (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2443 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

which I guess contains the explanation, but I can't understand it...

Comment: You should include that output in your question where we can see it properly formatted.